# Async Observable inside Async Observable

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, observable, rx-android

I got a little problem, I'm using RxJava to retrieve data from Server, and then check those data with those in local, the problem I start check files in local and store the data, then I start the observable i get the SUCCESS before the data completely downloaded then i receive the "initRemoteData" Result after success.

so what i need to do is to block the observable when i call "InitRemoteData" when the observable give the result i continue.

```
private Observable<CheckStatus> getCheckObservable() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        DataDTO dto;
        try {
            dto = Utils.decryptData(
                localfile.getNonce(),
                localfile.getEncryptedData(),
                password);
        } catch (WrongPasswordException e) {
            return Observable.just(CheckStatus.WRONG_PASSWORD);
        }
        try {
            storeDataPrefs(dto);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return Observable.just(CheckStatus.OTHER_ERROR);
        }
        storeDatabase(dto);

        initRemoteData();//<-Here i did call for another observable but the observable keep going without waiting it to finish.



        return Observable.just(CheckStatus.SUCCESS);
    });
}
```

Observable Call :

```
getCheckObservable()
        .subscribeOn(BackgroundSchedulers.getMultiThreadInstance())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(Subscribers.create(checkResult -> replaceFragment(
            CheckAccountCompleteFragment
                .newInstance(checkResult),
            AddToBackStack.FALSE)));
```

UPDATE :
initRemoteData code  :

```
Observable.zip(getObservable1()),//remote Data
            getObservable2(), // local Data
            (observableResult1,observableResult2)->{
                doSomethingWith(observableResult1,observableResult2); // compare between data
                return null;
            }).subscribeOn(BackgroundSchedulers.getMultiThreadInstance())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                    doSomething2(); // update fields
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got correctly you need to make `getCheckObservable()` to wait for both results? If yes: `Observable.combineLatest()` can help you.

UPDATE:
Okay, So why not just `return` this "waiting" Observable in "big" one
Like this:

```
Observable.zip(getObservable1()),//remote Data
        getObservable2(), // local Data
        (observableResult1,observableResult2)->{
            doSomethingWith(observableResult1,observableResult2); // compare between data

            return CheckStatus.SUCCESS;   // <-- CHANGES

        }).subscribeOn(BackgroundSchedulers.getMultiThreadInstance())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                doSomething2(); // update fields
            }
        });
```

And

```
private Observable<CheckStatus> getCheckObservable() {
return Observable.defer(() -> {
    DataDTO dto;
    try {
        dto = Utils.decryptData(
            localfile.getNonce(),
            localfile.getEncryptedData(),
            password);
    } catch (WrongPasswordException e) {
        return Observable.just(CheckStatus.WRONG_PASSWORD);
    }
    try {
        storeDataPrefs(dto);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return Observable.just(CheckStatus.OTHER_ERROR);
    }
    storeDatabase(dto);

    return initRemoteData();       // <-- CHANGES
});
}
```

Comment: in the getCheckObservable am already calling a Observable.zip in "initRemoteData" which is a separated feature, but I need some data there,the problem "initRemoteData" it may finish after the whole execution of getCheckObservable () it doesn't cause a problem for the main functionality but it could be better if I do it correctly :p

Comment: not sure did i get you correctly. Can you share `initRemoteData()` code?

Comment: i putted some simplified code , but enough to understand the idea